# sorting not working in IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I am working on a site that has worked in all major browsers. Now I upgraded to IE 11, and I am having problems with the sorting. I can't really describe the problem, instead, it is easier to see for yourself. Here is an example url:

https://nfts.dlbr.dk/Forms/ForsogPlacering.aspx

Click on the sign at the left of the column name, and you will see that it kinda messes up instead of sorting.
If you try it in an IE version lower than version 11, or firefox, it works correctly. I can't figure out what can be causing this. Any ideas?
I am using a displaylayout in my aspx file:

```
        <DisplayLayout ViewType="OutlookGroupBy" Version="4.00" AllowSortingDefault="OnClient" StationaryMargins="Header" AllowColSizingDefault="Free" AllowUpdateDefault="Yes" StationaryMarginsOutlookGroupBy="True" 
        HeaderClickActionDefault="SortMulti" Name="UltraWebGrid1" BorderCollapseDefault="Separate" AllowDeleteDefault="Yes" RowSelectorsDefault="No" TableLayout="Fixed" RowHeightDefault="20px" AllowColumnMovingDefault="OnServer" SelectTypeRowDefault="Extended">
    <GroupByBox>
    <Style BorderColor="Window" BackColor="ActiveBorder"></Style>
    </GroupByBox>

    <GroupByRowStyleDefault BorderColor="Window" BackColor="Control"></GroupByRowStyleDefault>

    <FooterStyleDefault BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="LightGray">
    <BorderDetails ColorTop="White" WidthLeft="1px" WidthTop="1px" ColorLeft="White"></BorderDetails>
    </FooterStyleDefault>

    <RowStyleDefault BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Solid" 

BackColor="Window">
<BorderDetails ColorTop="Window" ColorLeft="Window"></BorderDetails>

<Padding Left="3px"></Padding>
</RowStyleDefault>

<FilterOptionsDefault>
<FilterDropDownStyle BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="11px" Font-Names="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" BackColor="White" Width="200px" Height="300px" CustomRules="overflow:auto;">
<Padding Left="2px"></Padding>
</FilterDropDownStyle>

<FilterHighlightRowStyle ForeColor="White" BackColor="#151C55"></FilterHighlightRowStyle>
</FilterOptionsDefault>

<HeaderStyleDefault HorizontalAlign="Left" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="LightGray">
<BorderDetails ColorTop="White" WidthLeft="1px" WidthTop="1px" ColorLeft="White"></BorderDetails>
</HeaderStyleDefault>

<EditCellStyleDefault BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="None"></EditCellStyleDefault>

<FrameStyle BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="InactiveCaption" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="8.25pt" Font-Names="Microsoft Sans Serif" BackColor="Window" Width="100%" Height="100%"></FrameStyle>

<Pager MinimumPagesForDisplay="2">
<Style BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="LightGray">
<BorderDetails ColorTop="White" WidthLeft="1px" WidthTop="1px" ColorLeft="White"></BorderDetails>
</Style>
</Pager>

<AddNewBox Hidden="False">
<Style BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="InactiveCaption" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="Window">
<BorderDetails ColorTop="White" WidthLeft="1px" WidthTop="1px" ColorLeft="White"></BorderDetails>
</Style>
</AddNewBox>
</DisplayLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1) Install .NET 4.5 on the server – it has the browser detection problem fixed. If your server is 2003, then install the patches for the browser detection problem.

2) If you cannot install .NET 4.5, then try this:

- Open the App_Browsers folder in your application
- If you don't have that folder, right click on your Website project >> Add >> Add Asp.Net Folder >> App_Browsers. Add the file from

http://blogs.telerik.com/docs/default-source/marinbratanov_files/telerik_ie11_browser_file_fix.zip?sfvrsn=2

inside it.

Here's a link with more details:

http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11